# Python conditional syntax error

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and currently I am working on an income tax calculator and the first step I want the user to do is press 1 if they are married and then press 2 if they are single. What do I need to do to fix this code ? My IDE says there is a syntax error on line 3 "if (answer == 1)"

```
        print ("If you are married press 1 if you are single press 2")
        answer = raw_input("")
        if (answer == 1)
           {
              print "Enter your income";
           }
           elif (answer == 2):
           {
              print "Enter your income";
           }
```

Comment: You are forgetting your colon `:` at the end of the condition `if (answer == 1):`. Also, *please* *please* get rid of those curly braces.

Comment: In addition to getting rid of the curly braces, you'll find that the parenthses around the `if` condition are redundant too. I had a hard time believing this question wasn't mis-tagged for a moment.

Comment: `raw_input` in python2 and `input` in python3 return a string; not an integer. You need to either do `int(answer)` or do `answer == '1'`. Oh, and Python does not use curly braces.

Comment: @idjaw Thanks for the info also is there any particular reason I should get rid of the curly braces or is it just hard to look at ?

Comment: You need to get rid of them because Python does not use brackets for defining a block of code, instead it uses indentation. You really, really should read a tutorial first.

Comment: @0danderson0 Pretty much what  Óscar López just said. I strongly suggest reading through a tutorial to familiarize yourself with the rules of the language.

Comment: And as you are at it: don't use parens around the condition. Python is not C or C++!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not use curly braces like most other languages. Instead it uses a colon `:` and whitespace to determine blocks. You also do not need (and shouldn't put) semicolons `;` at the end of every line. In addition, you do not need parenthesis around conditions in if/while/etc. statements.This is the correct way to write your code:

```
print ("If you are married press 1 if you are single press 2")
answer = raw_input("")
if answer == 1:
    print "Enter your income"
elif answer == 2:
    print "Enter your income"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you forgot `:` after your first `if`. Secondly, you don't need `{}` in python, it uses tab space to know what is inside `if` or `while`. Thirdly, you need to convert the `raw_input()` to int you can do it as so `int(raw_input())`, and you don't have to put `""` inside it

also, Python doesn't need `;`

so after all, the code should look like this

```
print ("If you are married press 1 if you are single press 2")
answer = int(raw_input())
if (answer == 1):
    print "Enter your income"
elif (answer == 2):
    print "Enter your income"
```